# VS Code snippet and SimpleTypeName - different results depending upon order in XML?

Tags: c#, code-snippets

I'm writing a little snippet to generate C# properties *(as have many before me no doubt)*. I would like to add various attributes in the generated code, and would like to use the "SimpleTypeName" function. However, it seems that it doesn't always work, depending upon the order of the usage in the source XML file.

Specifically, given snippet XML like this...

```
<Snippet>
  <Declarations>
    <Literal Editable="false">
      <ID>DesignerSerializationVisibility</ID>
      <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility)</Function>
    </Literal>
    <Literal Editable="false">
      <ID>DebuggerStepThrough</ID>
      <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough)</Function>
    </Literal>
  </Declarations>

  <Code Language="CSharp">
    <![CDATA[

      [$DebuggerStepThrough$(),
       $DesignerSerializationVisibility$($DesignerSerializationVisibility$.Hidden)]
      public object x {get;set;}    

      [$DesignerSerializationVisibility$($DesignerSerializationVisibility$.Hidden),
       $DebuggerStepThrough$()]
      public object z {get;set;}    

    ]]>
  </Code>
</Snippet>
```

...and the appropriate "using" statements in my source file, I get code like this...

```
  [DebuggerStepThrough(),
   DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
  public object x { get; set; }

  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden),
   DebuggerStepThrough()]
  public object z { get; set; }
```

All fine and dandy. If, however, I change my snippet XML to be this *(note just the order of the functions has changed)*...

```
<Snippet>
  <Declarations>
    <Literal Editable="false">
      <ID>DesignerSerializationVisibility</ID>
      <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.ComponentModel.DesignerSerializationVisibility)</Function>
    </Literal>
    <Literal Editable="false">
      <ID>DebuggerStepThrough</ID>
      <Function>SimpleTypeName(global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough)</Function>
    </Literal>
  </Declarations>

  <Code Language="CSharp">
    <![CDATA[

      [$DesignerSerializationVisibility$($DesignerSerializationVisibility$.Hidden),
       $DebuggerStepThrough$()]
      public object z {get;set;}    

      [$DebuggerStepThrough$(),
       $DesignerSerializationVisibility$($DesignerSerializationVisibility$.Hidden)]
      public object x {get;set;}    

    ]]>
  </Code>
</Snippet>
```

...I get this as the inserted C# code:

```
  [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden),
   global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]
  public object z { get; set; }

  [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough(),
   DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
  public object x { get; set; }
```

Why does my call to SimpleTypeName(DebuggerStepThrough) seem not to work when the XML is written using the order in the second example ?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the second generated code?  To me, nothing looks wrong though it is slightly different with the `global` parts.  Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Well... I suppose technically there's nothing wrong with the code. My question was more one of why, given that in the first case it correctly omits the namespace from the attributes (the point of using SimpleTypeName ?) but in the second it doesn't (seemingly ignoring the SimpleTypeName call).

Comment: Oh my mistake, I misinterpreted what was going on and didn't know what `SimpleTypeName` did.  But I see what it's supposed to do now.  I guess the next logical question for me is, are you using the right namespaces?

Comment: Hi, well... yes, I'm using the correct namespaces - the code omits the namespaces just fine with the XML layed out as per example 1. Of course, contrary to what I said earlier, the generated code is not correct (the DebuggerStepThrough attribute is not valid in that location) so maybe when the snippet is expanded it gets it wrong as a result. Who knows...